# How to get both curved corners in a SVG clippath?

Tags: css, svg, clip-path

For a few days I struggle with a problem:
I've made a SVG clip-path and I would like to add curved corners to it.
When I add a 'C' of 'Curvetto' to the code, I get only a curved corner on the right.

This is my code:

```
<svg width="0" height="0">
    <defs>
      <clipPath id="myClip" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
        <path d="M0.23,0.1 C 0.77,0.1 0.77,0.1, 1,0, 1,1, 0,1,0.0,0.0z"/>
      </clipPath>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

[Image of my clip path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSO0g.png)

How do I get both corners curved?

Comment: Add some [arcs](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataEllipticalArcCommands) at appropriate points, or alternatively use bezier curves

Comment: Thanks @RobertLongson, but I would like to use the path as a mask

Comment: Your comment makes no sense. Why would adding arcs/additional curves stop you using it as a mask?

Comment: Because I saw that the arcs are single lines

Comment: Then you read it wrong, they form part of a larger path, just like the bezier curves you're already using.